# Schema Inheritance in BizTalk Server

Tags: xml, inheritance, schema, xsd, biztalk

I just wondering if anyone has already tried of doing something like schema inheritance in BizTalk schemas?

I am using WCF Adapter and using 'consume adapter service' to generate a schema automatically, what I wanted is instead of always generating a schema and since most of my schema is the same then I want to have something like a base schema.

I have this scenario that I'm testing flat file debatching, for debatching I need to set maxoccur property of the schema to '1' but for batch processing it should be '*', instead of creating a two different schemas I want just to create a base schema and inherit from it and then change the maxoccur property in the derived schema.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: BTW, I think you'll have to do it the other way around. All documents valid by the derived schema have to be valid by the base schema. The base could allow many elements, and the derived allow only one, but not the other way around.

Comment: Hi John,

Thanks for the reply but I don't completely understand your response, can you please explain it elaborately?

My example was simple only that I have a base schema and from my derived schema (imported) I changed the maxoccur property to '*', but when I tried to test it using FFDasm tool, it throws an exception than element (element datastructure type is the imported schema) is not declared.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you envelope your base schema?
  Then you can make the pipeline do the debatching for you ....  define the envelope structure with any "any" repeating inside it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003">
xmlns="urn:SomeProject:Schemas:1.0" targetNamespace="urn:SomeProject:Schemas:1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<b:schemaInfo is_envelope="yes" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:element name="Envelope">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo>
<b:recordInfo body_xpath="/*[local-name()='Envelope' and namespace-uri()='urn:SomeProject:Schemas:1.0']" />
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
**<xs:any />** 
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

then add to the collection in XMLDisassemble of the pipeline...